# fpdf php file with google analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, fpdf

On my website I automatically generate pdf worksheets with fpdf. I have a problem tracking these php files in Google Analytics. How to track a file like:

http://www.lessucces.nl/images/werkbladgenerator/rekenen/meten/matenomrekenencmnaarm.php

I got an answer from somebody that made the joomla plugin for google analytics, but he told me to put in between the  of the file, but I don't have  in my php file. This is the script he gave me:

```
   <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');  
    ga('create',  'UA*******-1');ga('send', 'pageview');</script><script 
    type="text/javascript" src="http://www.lessucces.nl/plugins/system/gauniversal4joomlapro/ga_tracking/extrascript_v2.js"></script>
```

Who knows how to solve this problem? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your example (joomla plugin) is pretty much irrelevant to your question - it measures clicks on links that lead to a download, it does not track a download if the file is called directly, what seems to be what you are after. Since you are generating the pdf file via php you could use the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide?hl=de) to track the download.

I can give you not a complete tutorial but at least a basic idea how to do this. The measurement protocol is simply a call to a url on the google tracking server that includes several parameters - which Google Account, client id, type of interaction, name of the document etc. Some parameters (like Account id) are mandatory, others (like document title) are optional.

First you'd need to check if the download is an existing user (as far as analytics is concerned), so you need to check if a first party cookie by the name of _ga exists ($_COOKIE['_ga']). If it  doesn't exists you must generate a new client id (google recommends the UUID format to avoid collisions).

Then you build your url with at least the following parameters

```
v=1             // Version. At the moment this is always "1" (but still a mandatory parameter)
&tid=UA-XXXX-Y  // Tracking ID / Property ID.
&cid=555        // Anonymous Client ID from the cookie or generated by you
&t=pageview             // Hit Type.
&dp=/myfile.php       // Page (Url for the document)
&dt=MyPDFfile    // Title for your document
```

the url for the Analytics server is  www.google-analytics.com/collect, so this will give you:

```
www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXX-Y&cid=555&t=pageview&&dp=/myfile.php&dt=MyPDFfile
```

You call this with fopen or via curl at the start of the script that generates the pdf file and it will register as a hit in analytics. If there have been other hits with the same client id these will be stitched together into sessions and users in the Ga interface.

Comment: Thank you very much for your amazing answer. It's a bit difficult for me, but with this answer I think I can figure it out after a while. THANKS!

Comment: I tried to call this with fopen and curl, but I can't get it to work. I can find information about fopen and curl, but I can't find anything that I can use in this situation. Any help?

Comment: "Can't get it to work" is a bit vague - what exactly is going wrong ? On some servers fopen is not allowed to open remote urls, so that might be a problem.